# Install Windows Store App package (*.appx) for all users

Tags: windows, windows-8, powershell, deployment, windows-store-app

I know there are several posts where users want to install Windows Store Apps for **all users**. Answers were to use `DISM`.

In my case I can not use `DISM` because all clients are already deployed. If a user requests a new app at the supports center, the package will be deployed to his machine.

This package (*.appx) should be deployed to the machine **not** only for the user.

**Is there a powershell command to achive this?**

Comment: The only way to do this I know us to run an elevated command prompt and point to the .appx file. The solution of course is create a script file that is ran when the user logs in, which will add the applications, which will run once. I don't believe there to be a solution which involves deploying to the machine rather then the user.  Powershell can manage what I describe with a simple script and the command add-appxpackage `C:\ContosoApp\ExpenseApp.appx`

Comment: this is who we do it now. ;) ... but one point is that we want to reduce the number of scripts running on startup.

Comment: Like I said the article I found is pretty clear.  It basically says there isn't a way to deploy a WS application to the machine unless you use the image method.  Of course that isn't different compared to say a desktop application.  You have to basically deploy the installation in a similar matter unless you build it into the application itself at least on Windows Vista and Windows 7.  Windows XP barely had the concept of user seperation.

Comment: does this work for windows 10 uwp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this through the `DISM.EXE /Online /Add-ProvisionedAppxPackage` command. More info [here](http://www.verboon.info/2012/02/managing-windows-8-metro-style-apps-with-dism/)

Comment: does this work for windows 10 uwp?

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Add-ProvisionedAppxPackage** with PowerShell script to install **[UWP Sideloading](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/package/packaging-uwp-apps)** packages with certificate:

1. You must choose a local or network path and copy all the package folder content.
2. Run **[powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell)** as `Administrator`:

```
$localFolderPath = "C:\UWP_1.0.0.0_Test]\*"
$localPackage = "C:\UWP_1.0.0.0_Test\UWP_1.0.0.0_x64.msixbundle"
$certName = Get-ChildItem -Path $localFolderPath -Include *.cer

certutil.exe -addstore TrustedPeople $certName[0].FullName
DISM.EXE /Online /Add-ProvisionedAppxPackage /PackagePath:$localPackage /SkipLicense
```

3. Wait, it takes a while.
4. If there are some depencies use `/DependencyPackagePath:[pathDependcies]`

I hope that I could help someone with that. :)