# How to install WSA on Windows 11 for my user

Tags: powershell, windows-11, uac, windows-packagemanagement, windows-subsystem-for-android

First of all, WSA is not available on Microsoft Store in my region. I searched online and performed the following steps:

1. Download the latest .msix bundle from https://store.rg-adguard.net/
2. Confirm `MicrosoftCorporationII.WindowsSubsystemForAndroid_2305.40000.6.0_neutral_~_8wekyb3d8bbwe.Msixbundle` is successfully downloaded (referred as `wsa.msixbundle` in this question)
3. Double click `wsa.msixbundle`. It prompts me to install WSA.
4. Click on "install" button (note there is a badge administrator icon on the left of the label)
5. UAC prompt appears, entered admin password correctly
6. **Error**: it says package installation failed, requires administrator and tells me to install via PowerShell's `Add-AppxPackage` cmdlet.
7. Open administrator PowerShell using `Win + x` `A`
8. Run `Add-AppxPackage C:\Users\[username]\Downloads\wsa.msixbundle`
9. Install succeeded (no error messages)
10. I can confirm WSA is now available for administrator, but not my regular user account

How to install WSA on Windows 11 for regular accounts or all accounts, like my own user account? I don't want to use administrator account all the time for several reasons.

Comment: See if this helps https://superuser.com/questions/647927/install-windows-store-app-package-appx-for-all-users

Comment: (1) Can't you change region, install WSA and then change back? (2)  Can you install the [Amazon Appstore app page](https://aka.ms/AmazonAppstore) from the Microsoft Store? (This will also install WSA.)

Comment: @harrymc - One cannot just change the region of a Microsoft Account. While you can change the locale of a Windows user, it won’t change, any region limitation’s associated with Windows Store.

Comment: Related link: https://github.com/K3V1991/How-to-download-and-install-WSA

Answer (score 0):

`Add-AppxPackage` only adds the package for the current user. To install for all users, follow these steps:

- Running as **Administrator**, provision the package for all users (newly created users will get it automatically):

```sh
Add-AppxProvisionedPackage -PackagePath "c:\folder\wsa.msixbundle"
```

- Running as target **user**, register the package by manifest:

```sh
$Manifest = Get-AppxProvisionedPackage -Online | 
  Where-Object -Property DisplayName -EQ $Name  | 
  Select-Object -ExpandProperty InstallLocation
Add-AppxPackage -Path $Manifest -Register
```

Comment: As the package itself is quite big (at 1.4GB), would it be a waste of storage to install it for all users? How can I install specifically for my user account?

Comment: @sudoer AppxPackage files are shared/deduplicated within appx volumes, so there's *generally* one copy of the base files and only user-specific data gets created per-user.

Comment: I see. So i should use `Add-AppxProvisionedPackage`, as admin. Correct?

Comment: @sudoer - That’s exactly what the answer is suggesting. You need to run both commands as instructed

Comment: But the above command isn't working. For `Add-AppxProvisionedPackage`, I see `InvalidArgument (:) ParameterBindingException` error. Help?

Comment: Edit: I needed to add `-Online -SkipLicense` for it to work. Also I somehow don't need to run the second command.